# Magento 2 : How to add custom zipcode field in braintree payment form and send in payment request?

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, braintree

I want to add a custom input field in the Braintree payment method form and send that field value to Braintree, for validate on Braintree side. How can I achieve this?

[image]

I want the input field for zip code and it should be required and it should be sent to Braintree when we click on the "Place Order" button.

Does anyone have any idea? please share.

Comment: Did you find any solution fr this?